# Rebuilding OWA / Exchange 2003

Tags: exchange-2003, outlook-web-app

Anyone have any experience rebuilding OWA? I am under the impression that this KB contains the process http://support.microsoft.com/?ID=280823 under the section "Method 1: Reset the HighWaterMarks"

I inherited an Exchange box that was never patched, and after getting up to date I'm getting some permissions issues.

If anyone has any warnings about using the above process let me know. Alternatively, can I simply uninstall and reinstall OWA from the Exchange 2003 CD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just uninstall and re-install OWA, its a built in component of Exchange.

I have used that article in the past to successfully fix some issues, particularly steps 5 and 6, which deals with placeholder image problems, that can occur quite often in exchange 2003.

You don't mention what you specific problem is, so I can't give you more details.

Comment: Viewing public folders was giving me an 'unspecified error' message, but now I think I've hosed some permissions. I can login, but trying to send or forward email is giving me 403 Forbidden errors

Answer (score 1):

Running /disasterrecovery with Exchange setup may fix the issues for you. It certainly can't do any harm.